# Trying to run a Makefile from the command line - '.' is not recognised

Tags: c, cmd, makefile, path-variables

I need some help with this. I am on Windows 10, and I am trying to run a Makefile to build a little C program. I did not write the Makefile, it is prescribed by the teacher to be used for testing (we cannot write our own tests for some reason).

This is the Makefile, in full:

```
LIB=./lib/mylist.c

TEST1=func_test1
TEST2=func_test2
TEST3=func_test3
TEST4=func_test4
TEST5=func_test5

TEST1_EXE=$(TEST1).out
TEST1_SRC=./tests/$(TEST1).c
TEST2_EXE=func_test2.out
TEST2_SRC=./tests/func_test2.c
TEST3_EXE=func_test3.out
TEST3_SRC=./tests/func_test3.c
TEST4_EXE=func_test4.out
TEST4_SRC=./tests/func_test4.c
TEST5_EXE=func_test5.out
TEST5_SRC=./tests/func_test5.c

all:
    gcc -std=c99 -o $(TEST1_EXE) $(TEST1_SRC) $(LIB) -I./include/
    gcc -std=c99 -o $(TEST2_EXE) $(TEST2_SRC) $(LIB) -I./include/
    gcc -std=c99 -o $(TEST3_EXE) $(TEST3_SRC) $(LIB) -I./include/
    gcc -std=c99 -o $(TEST4_EXE) $(TEST4_SRC) $(LIB) -I./include/
    gcc -std=c99 -o $(TEST5_EXE) $(TEST5_SRC) $(LIB) -I./include/

test:
    ./$(TEST1_EXE) > $(TEST1).youranswer
    diff $(TEST1).youranswer $(TEST1).answer >> scoring_result
    ./$(TEST2_EXE) > $(TEST2).youranswer
    diff $(TEST2).youranswer $(TEST2).answer >> scoring_result
    ./$(TEST3_EXE) > $(TEST3).youranswer
    diff $(TEST3).youranswer $(TEST3).answer >> scoring_result
    ./$(TEST4_EXE) > $(TEST4).youranswer
    diff $(TEST4).youranswer $(TEST4).answer >> scoring_result
    ./$(TEST5_EXE) > $(TEST5).youranswer
    diff $(TEST5).youranswer $(TEST5).answer >> scoring_result
```

So, to be clear, I did not write it. This should be functional.

Anyway, I open up the cmd, go to my directory, say "make" and it seems to be working. But when I write "make test", again on instructions from the teacher to make the tests run, I get the following response from the cmd:

```
./func_test1.out > func_test1.youranswer
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So it's probably a missing path variable (I've been having issues with those). But where in the world do I find the folder that the '.' command / lexeme is located?

Comment: http://www.cygwin.com/ can be installed quickly and easily on Windows. It is not a new OS. In the setup, choose gcc to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Makefile was written for a unix-like shell, not cmd. In particular, cmd needs

```
.\func_test1.out > func_test1.youranswer
```

(i.e. `\` backslash, not `/` slash).

Comment: Thanks, but now 'diff' is not recognised.

Comment: I don't know if it would be possible to install a shell that can run the Makefile just fine? Or if it would be easier to rewrite the Makefile to work with the cmd, and just replace it with the original when sending it back to the teacher?

Comment: @KeizerHarm `diff` is another standard unix tool that Windows doesn't come with. There's probably a `diff.exe` around somewhere, but the easiest way would be to just not use Windows.

Comment: Right, installing an entire new operating system on my already slow-running laptop probably won't fit with my priorities as well as the deadline for this assignment... I suppose that the best option would be for me to translate this Makefile into windows-speak then. Might teach me some commands too.

Comment: @KeizerHarm By the way, where did you get `make` and `gcc` from?

Comment: `make` I found here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
I can't recall deliberately installing `gcc`, it must have come with Mingw which I had installed earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181205/discussion-between-keizerharm-and-melpomene).